# Treating the values from a list of slots and strings

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I want to do a macro in common lisp which is supposed to take in one of its arguments a list made of slots and strings. Here is the prototype :

```
(defclass time-info ()
  ((name :initarg name)
   (calls :initarg calls)
   (second :initarg second)
   (consing :initarg consing)
   (gc-run-time :initarg gc-run-time)))

(defun print-table (output arg-list time-info-list) ())
```

The idea is to print a table based on the arg-list which defines its structure. Here is an example of a call to the function:

```
(print-table *trace-output*
             '("|" name "||" calls "|" second "\")
             my-time-info-list)
```

This print a table in ascII on the trace output. The problem, is that I don't know how to explicitely get the elements of the list to use them in the different parts of my macro.

I have no idea how to do this yet, but I'm sure it can be done. Maybe you can help me :)

Comment: Why should it be a Macro and not a Function? ASCII representation of the array? Which array?

Comment: The `:initarg`s are usually keywords, and you should define accessors or readers for your slots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would base this on `format`.  The idea is to build a format string
from your `arg-list`.

I define a helper function for that:

```
(defun make-format-string-and-args (arg-list)
  (let ((symbols ()))
    (values (apply #'concatenate 'string
                   (mapcar (lambda (arg)
                             (ctypecase arg
                               (string 
                                (cl-ppcre:regex-replace-all "~" arg "~~"))
                               (symbol
                                (push arg symbols)
                                "~a")))
                           arg-list))
            (nreverse symbols))))
```

Note that `~` must be doubled in `format` strings in order to escape them.

The printing macro itself then just produces a `mapcar` of `format`:

```
(defmacro print-table (stream arg-list time-info-list)
  (let ((time-info (gensym)))
    (multiple-value-bind (format-string arguments)
        (make-format-string-and-args arg-list)
      `(mapcar (lambda (,time-info)
                 (format ,stream ,format-string
                         ,@(mapcar (lambda (arg)
                                     (list arg time-info))
                                   arguments)))
               ,time-info-list)))
```

You can then call it like this:

```
(print-table *trace-output*
             ("|" name "||" calls "|" second "\\")
             my-time-info-list)
```

Please note the following errors in your code:

- You need to escape `\` in strings.
- `Second` is already a function name exported from the `common-lisp`
  package.  You should not clobber that with a generic function.

Answer (score 1):

You need to be more precise with your requirements. Macros and Functions are different things. Arrays and Lists are also different.

We need to iterate over the `TIME-INFO-LIST`. So that's the first `DOLIST`.

The table has a description for a line. Each item in the description is either a slot-name or a string. So we iterate over the description. That's the second `DOLIST`. A string is just printed. A symbol is a slot-name, where we retrieve the slot-value from the current `time-info` instance.

```
(defun print-table (stream line-format-description time-info-list)
  (dolist (time-info time-info-list)
    (terpri stream)
    (dolist (slot-or-string line-format-description)
      (princ (etypecase slot-or-string
               (string slot-or-string)
               (symbol (slot-value time-info slot-or-string)))
             stream))))
```

Test:

```
> (print-table *standard-output*
               '("|" name "||" calls "|" second "\\")
               (list (make-instance 'time-info
                                    :name "foo"
                                    :calls 100
                                    :second 10)
                     (make-instance 'time-info
                                    :name "bar"
                                    :calls 20
                                    :second 20)))

|foo||100|10\
|bar||20|20\
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you probably don't want the quote there, if you're using a macro (you do want it there if you're using a function, however). Second, do you want any padding between your separators and your values? Third, you're probably better off with a function, rather than a macro.

You also seem to be using "array" and "list" interchangeably. They're quite different things in Common Lisp. There are operations that work on generic sequences, but typically you would use one way of iterating over a list and another to iterate over an array.

Comment: Yeah, I'm still learning with macros, I was not sure, but you're right, a quote is not necessary.

Comment: For the padding, it should be an option that I did not include in the example. The idea is that it may not be necessary for the user. For the third, I was not sure what between functions and macros. I used the word array, because it's what you get when you print it. I'll edit this in my message :)

Comment: @The third man - You probably get a table when you print it. :)